# Handling backpressed on each fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, onbackpressed

I have browsed a lot on stackoverflow and have made a best set of transactions for my project but have issue while handling backpressed.

This is my baseactivity class:

```
public class BaseAppCompatActivity extends LifecycleActivity {
    protected IBackPressedListener onBackPressedListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }


    protected FragmentTransaction getFragmentTransaction() {
        return getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    }

    protected void addFragment(int fragmentContainer, Fragment fragment, String fragName, boolean addToBackStack) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentTransaction();
        ft.add(fragmentContainer, fragment);
        if (addToBackStack)
            ft.addToBackStack(fragName);
        // Complete the changes added above
        ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }

    public void setOnBackPressedListener(IBackPressedListener onBackPressedListener) {
        this.onBackPressedListener = onBackPressedListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        onBackPressedListener = null;
    }
}
```

This is my activity clas where I am adding the fragments and handling the backpressed events:

```
public class RechargeFragmentActivity extends BaseAppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recharge_fragment);

        /*Replace fragment*/
        addFragment(R.id.fragmentFrame, new SelectRechargeOperatorFragment(), AppFragments.FRAG_SELECT_RECHARGE_OPERATORS, true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1 && onBackPressedListener != null) {
            onBackPressedListener.onBackPressed();
        } else
            finish();
    }

}
```

Now I implement Onbackpressed listener in fragment and it works fine for one backpressed, after that it picks up the instance of last fragment only which is popped off.

```
public class SelectRechargeOperatorFragment extends BaseFragment {
    @Inject
    public SelectRechargeOperatorLiveDataModel operatorLiveDataModel;
    @BindView(R.id.rv_select_operator)
    RecyclerView rvSelectOperators;
    @BindView(R.id.proceedLayout)
    RelativeLayout btnProceed;
    private RechargeOperatorsAdapter adapter;


    public SelectRechargeOperatorFragment() {
        //empty constructor required
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ((BaseAppCompatActivity) fragmentContext).setOnBackPressedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onInject(GraphComponent applicationComponent) {
        super.onInject(applicationComponent);
        applicationComponent.inject(this);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_select_recharge_operator, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, convertView);

        /*fetch-views*/
        setUpOperatorRecyclerView();
        proceedToRecharge();

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    private void proceedToRecharge() {
        btnProceed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addFragment(R.id.fragmentFrame, new RechargeAirtimeFargment(), AppFragments.FRAG_RECHARGE_AIRTIME_PLANS, true);
            }
        });
    }
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }


}
```

This works well when I add only one fragment. When I add multiple fragments it works well only for first popping of fragment after that it returns me the old fragment onBackpressed listener. Why ?

Comment: Maintain currentfragment and check if(currentfragment instanceOf fragment) on onBackPress and do whatever you want to do on OnBackPress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, each time you add a fragment the `onBackPressedListener`  in your activity is being overriden by the new object. So after popping the last fragment  the logic fails. Try the following.

1. Remove the `setOnBackPressedListener` and `onBackPressedListener`  from your Activity
2. Implement `IBackPressedListener` in your fragments. May be you can use a basefragment to avoid code duplication. Choose based on your need.
3. Change the `onBackPressed` in your activity as,

   ```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
           if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
               Fragment currentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentFrame);
              if(null != currentFragment && currentFragment instance of IBackPressedListener) {
                  ((IBackPressedListener)currentFragment).onBackPressed();
              }
           } else
               finish();
       }
   ```

Comment: Awesome @vishnu. Worked well